# Plumber R package - post request not working

Tags: r, post, plumber

I try to make post request with plumber package.

```
library(jsonlite)
#* @post /sum
addTwo <- function(a, b){
  x <- as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)
  return(x)
}
```

And then I write

`library("plumber") r <- plumb("C:/.../post.R")`

but then the error comes up:

> Warning message: In readLines(file) :   incomplete final line found on
>   'C:/.../post.R'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a warning that says that you don't have a trailing newline in your `post.R` file. You can ignore it or add an empty line at the end of the file to make it go away.

The actual problem is that you're not ever running the API, only defining it.

```
# Load Plumber
library("plumber") 

# define the plumber router in the variable r
r <- plumb("C:/.../post.R")

# Run r on port 8000
r$run(port=8000)
```